# Laptop does not power off after it has been suspended to ram

Tags: gentoo, suspend, acpi

I suspend my laptop using `echo mem > /sys/power/state`. That works fine and it resumes nicely. Once I try to power it off, it shuts down fine until i see the message `Power down.` (or similar). Needless to say, it stops there, completely.

Why? How to avoid?

- Gentoo ~amd64
- Vanilla kernel 3.0.4
- Dell Latitude E6400
- lspci: http://pastebin.com/b0BYGHAQ
- kernel conf: http://paste.pocoo.org/show/471271/
- dmesg: http://paste.pocoo.org/show/471320/

  - With acpi debug: http://paste.pocoo.org/show/486337/
  - with acpi debug after resume: http://paste.pocoo.org/show/486338/
  - without wl after resume: http://paste.pocoo.org/show/487374/
- modules: wl (broadcom wlan)

Comment: How are you trying to shutdown?  This is normal behavior for `shutdown -H`, but `shutdown -P` should power off.

Comment: This is strange if you shutdown properly (as psusi suggested). Try recompiling the kernel with `CONFIG_ACPI_DEBUG` enabled and post the new dmesg.

Comment: @psusi I'm using 'halt'. If I didn't suspend it works just fine. Only after one S-R cycle it doesn't power off anymore.

Comment: @rozcietrzewiacz enabled acpi debug, attached two pastes, one before, one after S-R. As I'm writing this I realized the later one would have been enough :-D ...

Comment: Try disabling the aspm=force, wl, and nuovu modules.

Comment: @psusi disabling aspm=force didn't make a difference, nouveau is my only video driver, compiled in so I can't test that. I'll update this as soon as I try unloading wl.

Comment: So how's this going for you with the newer kernel versions?

Comment: I have another laptop now and there is such issue anymore. The original issue never got resolved though.

Answer (score 1):

You need to provide at least your kernel config, dmesg and lsmod output for people to be able to say anything meaningful. Shutdown functionality is ACPI-related, so I would check everything ACPI first.

Comment: I attached it. Can you elaborate on how to check acpi?

Comment: lspci is not lsmod. also added dmesg to the answer. looking at kernel config everything is built in, so dmesg might provide some helpful hints about things possibly broken.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I misread for lsmod for lspci, my bad. Attached dmesg and modules info.

Comment: Does the question title mean that the device does power off normally off a cold boot with no previous suspend cycle?

Comment: @Ikraav: exactly.

Answer (score 0):

I just noticed that all your `dmesg` contain a call trace that indicates something tried to access the system log using a deprecated call. As you out ruled the `wl` driver and probably the kernel itself as well, what is left are userspace and hardware. Another look at the `dmesg` made me notice that the call trace refers to `syslog-ng`. An `emerge -vuDa1 syslog-ng` should not harm and may help.

Comment: Did not load wl: same problem, still prints out a stack trace. See newest dmesg.

Comment: Using latest broadcom-sta version (5.100.82.38-r1), which is the most recent driver for any broadcom stuff. I'm pretty sure that's not outdated. Chipset does not seem to be supported by the kernel itself.

Comment: _Vanilla_ means unmodified. As in the latest, officially released (_stable_), unmodified kernel. Also, I had the problem before 3.0, too.

Comment: Well, bad shot then. But I have another idea: it says *"Pid: 2148, comm: syslog-ng"* - maybe syslog-ng is misbehaving. What version do you have? If it's below `3.2.4`, try upgrading (again, this is to take care for the evident error in dmesg, but may not yet solve the whole issue).

Comment: About vanilla: Well, I can see that the aspect of *vanilla- vs gentoo- sources* is a bit of a discussion. The [genpatches site](http://dev.gentoo.org/~dsd/genpatches/about.htm) claims that gentoo-sources are focused on stability and I'm used to trust gentoo-sources in that matter. But I believe you are right that vanilla *should* be stable.